# Get day name from Date and Day number of the Month in PHP

Tags: php

I have problem to convert Date to Day.For eg: today date is 16-03-2018, current equivalent day is Friday, This Friday is third Friday of the month. so I need to find Day, to Which Day of the Month in php.

Thanks,

Comment: and can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: can't you just google this? `get day name from date using php` or `get week number from date using php`

Comment: yes Also I found that above two php functions, but i cant  to find the Day to Which day of month in php @ Ghost

Comment: @user3839366 please check my answer.

Comment: @user3839366 please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
$datelist = date("Y/m/d");

$daylist = date('l', strtotime($datelist));

function dayNumber($date=''){
    if($date==''){
        $t=date('d-m-Y');
    } else {
        $t=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date));
    }

    $dayName = strtolower(date("D",strtotime($t)));
    $dayNum = strtolower(date("d",strtotime($t)));
    $return = floor(($dayNum - 1) / 7) + 1;
    return $return;
}

echo $daylist.'&nbsp;'.dayNumber($datelist).'of the Month';
```